# Differences between .Net Hashtable, Java Hashtable & HashMap

Tags: c#, java, .net, hashtable, hashmap

Am I correct in saying that a .Net Hashtable is not synchronized while a Java Hashtable is? And at the same time a Java HashMap is not synchronized and has better performance?

I am rewriting a Java app that makes heavy use of HashMaps in C# and I would like to use a HashTable and ensure that the performance is basically equivalent.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear about what your goals are in asking this question. Please consider revising a bit so it's more clear what you're hoping to learn exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you're asking is if HashMaps in Java and HashTables in C# act in roughly the same way and you're largely correct from a performance point of view. HashMaps as I recall do not complain if you insert duplicate keys whereas HashTable in C# will.

Answer (score 0):

By default, .NET Hashtables are not synchronized, but you can create a synchronized wrapper around one, like so:

```
Hashtable myHash = Hashtable.Synchronized(new Hashtable());
```